# Exchange Routing agent - check if email address is an Exchange Distribution List with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, exchange-server, agent

i'm tring to build a routing agent dll for exchange 2010, that will check if the recipient email address is an Exchange Distribution List.
if it is, i want to get the email adresses that are part of the distribution list.

**so basically i need two things:**

1. query exchange to check if the email address is a simple mail or a D-group
2. get all distribution group email members.

i'm working on visual studio 2013 with c# , and new working with exchange, 
what is the namespace/package i should work with to do these things ?

thanks.

David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use the AddressBook class to do that eg use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564676(v=exchg.150).aspx which will return https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.addressbookentry.recipienttype(v=exchg.150).aspx
2. You can fork or expand the recipients of a message in a Transport Agent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.routing.queuedmessageeventsource.expandrecipients(v=exchg.150).aspx if you want to expand a list that would requires an AD call which can be very costly in terms of performance in a Transport Agent.

Comment: i notices that when the massage "to" field contains a D-grp the .recepients are the specific Group members, im now looking for a way to mod the email so the individual recepients will fill the "To" field. and et rid ot the origional D-group. i need this for later use, i have an app that recieves the email, and uses the recepients to authenticate ad users, so the D-group email address is ot good for me.

Comment: Then modify the P2 recipients http://www.websense.com/support/article/t-kbarticle/What-are-P1-and-P2-headers-in-SMTP. But really why don't you just implement the expansion in the app that receives the message that would be the most efficient and easy thing to do.

Comment: the 3rd party app is closed, i dont have any control of it input methods